# Group Values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have following data in csv file. I want to groupby values on 'Value' column such that it breaks and prints the count of **True** and **False** if got atleast two consective values. I want to achieve this by using pandas because i will have the huge data and need to compute in lesser time.

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-05-16 17:54:30 | True |
| 2022-05-16 17:54:50 | True |
| 2022-05-16 17:55:01 | True |
| 2022-05-16 17:57:34 | False |
| 2022-05-16 17:57:44 | True |
| 2022-05-16 17:57:44 | True |
| 2022-05-16 17:57:54 | False |
| 2022-05-16 17:58:35 | False |
| 2022-05-16 18:31:43 | False |
| 2022-05-16 18:31:43 | False |
| 2022-05-16 18:31:43 | True |
| 2022-05-16 18:31:54 | True |
| 2022-05-16 18:31:54 | True |
| 2022-05-16 18:31:54 | False |
| 2022-05-16 18:32:45 | False |
| 2022-05-16 18:32:45 | False |
| 2022-05-16 18:32:45 | False |
| 2022-05-16 18:33:15 | True |
| 2022-05-16 18:33:15 | False |
| 2022-05-16 18:33:25 | False |
| 2022-05-16 18:33:25 | False |

**Output should be like this**

```
True: 5
False: 1
2022-05-16 17:57:44

True: 0
False: 4
2022-05-16 18:31:43

True: 3
False: 0
2022-05-16 18:31:54

True: 1
False: 7
2022-05-16 18:33:25
```

Comment: What do you consider "at least two consecutive values"?

Comment: @jjsantoso same values appearing in two consective records

Comment: There are only two rows with date=="2022-05-16 17:57:44" in the data example you provided, but the output suggests there are 6 rows

Comment: Output displays the date of last record when next two consective 'Value' occur like true, true or false, false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you have to create a variable that indicates when a new "phase" start and end. A new phase is when a break occurs, that is, when a row is followed by  two consecutive values that are different from the actual row. To get this `phase`, first I created a column "sum_next_two", which for each row, calculates the sum of the next two rows. We are interested in rows where `sum_next_two==2` or `sum_next_two==0`, because they indicate the start/end of a new phase. So, when `phase==True` it's a positive phase that ends when `sum_next_two==0`. Then, start a negative phase (`phase==False`) that ends when `sum_next_two==0`. After identifying all the existing phases, make a variable `group` that create a unique number for each phase.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [{'Date': '2022-05-16 17:54:30', 'Value': True},
 {'Date': '2022-05-16 17:54:50', 'Value': True},
 {'Date': '2022-05-16 17:55:01', 'Value': True},
 {'Date': '2022-05-16 17:57:34', 'Value': False},
 {'Date': '2022-05-16 17:57:44', 'Value': True},
 {'Date': '2022-05-16 17:57:44', 'Value': True},
 {'Date': '2022-05-16 17:57:54', 'Value': False},
 {'Date': '2022-05-16 17:58:35', 'Value': False},
 {'Date': '2022-05-16 18:31:43', 'Value': False},
 {'Date': '2022-05-16 18:31:43', 'Value': False},
 {'Date': '2022-05-16 18:31:43', 'Value': True},
 {'Date': '2022-05-16 18:31:54', 'Value': True},
 {'Date': '2022-05-16 18:31:54', 'Value': True},
 {'Date': '2022-05-16 18:31:54', 'Value': False},
 {'Date': '2022-05-16 18:32:45', 'Value': False},
 {'Date': '2022-05-16 18:32:45', 'Value': False},
 {'Date': '2022-05-16 18:32:45', 'Value': False},
 {'Date': '2022-05-16 18:33:15', 'Value': True},
 {'Date': '2022-05-16 18:33:15', 'Value': False},
 {'Date': '2022-05-16 18:33:25', 'Value': False},
 {'Date': '2022-05-16 18:33:25', 'Value': False}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# for each row, calculates the sum of the next two rows
df['sum_next_two'] = df['Value'].rolling(2).sum().shift(-2).fillna(method='ffill')

# We are interested in rows where sum_next_two==2 or sum_next_two==0, because they indicate the start/end of a new phase
df.loc[0, 'phase'] = True
df.loc[df['sum_next_two'].eq(2), 'phase'] = True
df.loc[df['sum_next_two'].eq(0), 'phase'] = False
df['phase'] = df['phase'].shift(1).fillna(method='ffill')
# identify uniquely each phase
df['group'] = df['phase'].diff().abs().cumsum().fillna(method='bfill')
df
```

[image]

After that, then simply aggregate to get the desired output:

```py
df.groupby('group').agg(total_true=('Value', 'sum'), total_rows=('Value', 'count'), date=('Date', 'max'))\
    .assign(total_false=lambda x: x['total_rows'] - x['total_true'])\
    [['date', 'total_true', 'total_false']]
```

[image]